# help solving for more variables

Tags: probability

I have the formula $\mu_S = n \times (ap + b(1-p))$

I know that $b = ((\mu_s/n) - ap) / (1-p)$

Can I read some explanation how this is done for $b$?, and how also to do for $a$ and maybe $n$ also, so I can understand.  Wolfram-alpha takes off the $n \times$ from original formula $\mu_S = n \times (ap + b(1-p))$. This is not trolling question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $\mu_s = n \cdot (ap + b(1-p))$ Divide both sides by $n$: $\frac{\mu_s}{n} = ap + b(1-p)$. Next, subtract $ap$ from both sides: $\frac{\mu_s}{n}-ap = b(1-p)$. Do you see it now? The approach is to isolate the variable that you need to express on one side so gradually move everything that does not contain that variable to the other side.